# Unit Testing DialogFragments

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation, android-dialogfragment

I use a custom layout for my DialogFragment which I launch like this:

```
someDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog_tag");
```

The Dialog has two text fields, a "Save" and "Cancel" button and when the user presses "Save", it does some validation and displays red text if it fails. Think of a login popup when login fails.

How do I test this using Junit in Android? I want to test if:

1. The dialog is displaying when the user presses something.
2. The red text is displaying when validation fails.

Specifically, how do I get a handle of the views within DialogFragment using the Android Instrumentation framework when it launches from an Activity? How do I know the DialogFragment is displaying correctly?

Comment: You should take a look at the recently introduced `uiautomator` API for [UI testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html). To 'listen' for the dialog(fragment) opening, you'll probably have to use a `UiWatcher`. For the red text, refer to the functionality `UiObject` offers. // Edit: [this blogpost](http://everybodytests.blogspot.co.nz/2012/11/uiautomator-and-watchers-adding-async.html) may give you some more pointers related to `uiautomator` and dialogs.